# PHP-FPM on CentOS 8 - different user

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf, fpm

I'm using apache and PHP-FPM on CentOS8, but I am running apache as the `nidb` user. I've changed all of the config file locations I think I need to the `nidb` username/group, but I still get an error about `/run/php-fpm/www.sock` permissions once I restart php-fpm and apache.

When I manually change permissions of `/run/php-fpm/www.sock` to 0777 or change the owner to `nidb`, the website works with no errors. If I restart the php-fpm service, the owner is reset to root, and the website gives the error again.

In `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` I have

```
User nidb
Group nidb
```

In `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` I have

```
user = nidb
group = nidb
listen.owner = nidb
listen.group = nidb
listen.mode = 0660
```

`ps` shows that `/user/sbin/httpd` is started by `root`, and then launches a few processes owned by `nidb`. `ps` shows the same thing for php-fpm.

Answer (score 1):

When listen.acl_users is set, listen.owner & listen.group are ignored, comment:

```
;listen.acl_users = apache,nginx
;listen.acl_groups =
```

then restart php-fpm